# JS | isolate chrome.tabs.query({active:true} event to specific window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have the following script trigger from a browser extension with the idea that it will edit the URL and load the page with the new URL. This works as expected until a certain point.

```
$('#Change_btn').click(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true},tabs=>{
        url=tabs[0].url.replace("en-US","nb-NO")
        chrome.tabs.update({url})
    })
  });
```

I discovered that if I have multiple Chrome windows open, the script will chose a random active tab, and load this in the tab I have open in the window I trigger the script from.

Is it possible to specify / isolate this script to the actual window where the script is triggered? If so, how would I do this?

### Solved

Added `currentWindow: true` to  `chrome.tabs.query({active:true},tabs=>{` making the finished script look like this:

```
$('#Change_btn').click(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow: true},tabs=>{
        url=tabs[0].url.replace("en-US","nb-NO")
        chrome.tabs.update({url})
    })
  });
```

Comment: Add `currentWindow: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `currentWindow: true` to  `chrome.tabs.query({active:true},tabs=>{` making the finished script look like this:

```
$('#Change_btn').click(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow: true},tabs=>{
        url=tabs[0].url.replace("en-US","nb-NO")
        chrome.tabs.update({url})
    })
  });
```